# How to use React to reconstruct serialized DOM in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, dom, serialization, reactjs

In my application, I serialize DOM into JSON and send it back to server.

I need help finding an efficient way to later reconstruct the DOM from this serialized JSON using React.

To share a concrete example, let's start with this DOM:

```
    <div id="parent">
      <div id="one"></div>
      <span id="two"></span>
    </div>
```

This will get serialized into following JSON:

```
    [
      {
        "index": 0,
        "tagName": "DIV",
        "attributes": {"id": "parent"}
      },
      {
        "index": 1,
        "parent": 0,
        "tagName": "DIV",
        "attributes": {"id": "one"}
      },
      {
        "index": 2,
        "parent": 0,
        "tagName": "SPAN",
        "attributes": {"id": "two"}
      }
    ]
```

Now, in vanilla Javascript, I can re-build DOM like following:

```
    var nodes = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var node = json[i];

        // Create element
        var element = document.createElement(node.tagName);

        // Add attributes
        for (var attribute in node.attributes) {
            element.setAttribute(attribute, node.attributes[attribute]);
        }

        // Add parent-child association
        if (node.parent != undefined) nodes[node.parent].appendChild(element);

        // Cache it for later reference
        nodes[node.index] = element;
    }
```

I'm new to React, and so far I haven't figured out a way to establish dynamic parent-child relationship between components that I can change later. What would be a good way to accomplish this using React, or may be, is it even a good application of React?

The example above is a reduced example, but you can imagine the complexity can increase as different JSON instructions are introduced to re-parent, add or remove a particular DOM node.

Answer (score 2):

If you deserialize your JSON recursively it saves the need to manage parent-child relations explicitly.

Provide your JSON-HTML representation as a tree (rather than a list), and make sure your serialization observes a consistent pattern for all tags - they can then (at least in theory) be interpreted by the same React component.

Somewhat elaborate below, two things to note

- Each tag needs a unqiue key, e.g. a hash or application-id
- All nodes - and specifically text-only nodes - need a html root (I've chosen the tag `<text>` to enable text-only content in `<p>` and `<div>` bodies

Output should be

```
<div id="root_node">
  <div>
    <p><i>hi </i><b>there </b><text>friend</text></p>
    <p><b>hey</b></p>
  </div>
  <p><i>hey again</i></p>
</div>
```

React code

```
class JsonToHtml extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      json_html:
      { node : 'root',
        child: [
          { type: 'parent', tag: 'div', key: '84a4fb',
            child: [
              { type: 'parent', tag: 'p', key: '1bb600',
                child: [
                  {type: 'child', tag: 'i', val: 'hi ', key: 'f6a3ad'},
                  {type: 'child', tag: 'b', val: 'there ', key: '57ef5e'},
                  {type: 'child', tag: 'text', val: 'friend', key: '57ef52'}
                ]
              },
              { type: 'parent', tag: 'p', key: 'a43a9f',
                child: [
                  {type: 'child', tag: 'b', val: 'hey', key: '4e2d46'},
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          { type: 'parent', tag: 'p', key: '3e21f6',
            child: [
              {type: 'child', tag: 'i', val: 'hey again', key: 'ed5a49'},
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id='root_node'>
        {this.state.json_html.child.map(function(node) {
          return (
            <HtmlComponent key={node.key} node={node} />
          )
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
} export default JsonToHtml

class HtmlComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    if (this.props.node.type == "child") {
      return React.createElement(
          this.props.node.tag, {},
          this.props.node.val)
    }

    if (this.props.node.type == "parent") {
      return React.createElement(
          this.props.node.tag, {},
          this.props.node.child.map(function(node) {
            return (
                <HtmlComponent key={node.key} node={node} />
            )
          })
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use should use

```
React.createElement(type, props, children)
```

-

```
type:  can be string or ReactClass, in your case you can 'DIV', 'SPAN'

props: are properties of element, in your case you pass {id:'elm_id',className:'css_class'}

children: This is where you build hierarchy. This can be reactText, reactNode, reactFragment (reactNodes)
```

I am not writing the loop, I am just explaining how to create hierarchy.

```
var child1 = React.createElement('div',{id:'one'}, null);
var child2 = React.createElement('span',{id:'two'}, null);
var reactFragment = [child1,child2];
var parent = React.createElement('div',{id:'parent'}, reactFragment);
```